# Large Files into a List

Tags: python, list, large-files

I was wondering how I could put a really large file into a list? The code I have only works for small files:

```
def populate_director_to_movies(f):
    '''
    (file open for reading) -> dict of {str: list of str}
    '''

    movies = []
    line = f.readline()

    while line != '':
        movies.append(line)
        line = f.readline()
```

When I use this for a really large text file, it's just a blank space.

Comment: `f.readlines()` does the exact same thing

Comment: If the file is too big to store in memory, you don't store it in memory. Why do you need to store the whole thing?

Comment: The file has a Riding (0-307) and a certain amount of political parties that are chosen. The program I'm working on .. I have to pick a riding and return the amount parties in each file. The parties are N, L, C, and G and the riding has a bunch of these. So, I figured I'd turn it into a dictionary and the keys would be the riding and the values would be the political parties .. {Riding 14: N, L, G, C, N, N, C, G, L, C, L C}.

Comment: Lot of these questions lately: http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~csc108h/winter/assignments/a2/handout/index.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Python's `with` statement?

```
def populate_director_to_movies(f):
    with open(f) as fil:
        movies= fil.readlines()
```

Or if the file is too large for memory, do it by using a file iterator.

```
def populate_director_to_movies(f):
    movies = []
    with open(f) as fil:
        for line in fil:
            movies.append(line)
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the with statement, but for the large file, could I write as:

def populate_director_to_movies(f):
    '''
    (file open for reading) -> dict of {str: list of str}
    '''

    movies = []
    f = open('f.txt')

    for line in f:
        movies.append(line)
        line = f.readline()

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but that won't work. I've edited my answer to clarify how you can add to the movies list line-by-line

Answer (score 0):

If the file is huge, iterate over the file (or create a generator), and process the line.
Something like:

```
for line in f:
    process_line(line)
```